# React js setstate not working on much browsers

Tags: reactjs

I'm stuck with setstate in reactjs. Initially I was implementing as

```
var versions = [1,2,3,4];
this.setState({
    options: versions
});
```

The above code is working fine in Google Chrome but in IE 10 and Firefox it not working.

Later I changed to :

```
var oState = {}
oState['options'] = versions;
this.setState(oState);
```

But the issue didn't resolved. Both the code is only working in Google Chrome not in other browsers.

Please do let me know how can I solve this issue.

Comment: both the ways are correct and will work also, issue is somewhere else. Can you show the code where you are doing this `setState`

Comment: Hey Mayank, thank you for reply. I'm calling above code in plane function. The code will be executed once I call the function. I can't post you complete code as it very huge. Just let me know if you have any other options other than this.

Comment: check console are you getting any error ? if it is failing somewhere, it will log the error.

Comment: Yes I tried all possible stuff to find where it's getting stuck. But the flow is very much clear. No error and log in console..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare first your options in the state of the constructor?

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    options: null
  }
 }
```

But i'm not sure if it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes Thomas, as you have mentioned I've defined it as an array in constructor