# React setstate only works in one browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, use-state

I am trying to create a chat application with reactjs,nodejs and socket io.I am trying to set a value to a react usestate whenever a new message is sent,but it only works in one browser.For example,when I send a message from Chrome to Firefox ,the value of the useState changes in FireFox.But When I send a message from Firefox to chrome,the value does not change in Chrome.There is no problem in the backend.

**Here is the code:**

```
 const[msg,setmsg]=useState(null)

 useEffect(()=>{
   socket?.current.on("chat",(s)=>{
     setmsg(s)
     console.log(s)//logs an object
   })
 },[])

 useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(msg)//logs an object in one browser only
 },[msg])
```

[I think that this question is simillar to the one that I am asking,but it has not been answered yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610684/react-js-setstate-not-working-on-much-browsers)

Comment: looks like the issue is because of the socket not because of the useEffect...just verify whether socket is getting connected successfully in chrome

Comment: @ 
Arun pandian M
The socket is connected successfully in both the browser,because when I console.log(s),it successfully logs the message,in both of them.

Comment: since my answer didn't help you, I remove it. hope to get the proper answer soon bro.

Comment: No problem.And thanks for clearing so many doubts of mine!